# liquibase to load data from table

Tags: liquibase

how can i load data from database table to csv file using liquibase? I want select query output to be stored using liquibase.

is that possible?

Thanks
Chintan

Answer (score 0):

Luquibase can 'reverse engineer' an existing database with **generateChangeLog**, which will create a *changelog* that corresponds the the databased current state. Check the official documentation for details

https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html

Comment: generatechangelog is creating database. I want output of select query of one table stored in csv/txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the  dataOutputDirectory parameter to generateChangeLog option.

–dataOutputDirectory=DIR    Output data as CSV in the given directory   Optional
see

https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html

Comment: does it create output of select query of table?